# Magento 2 font-display: swap

Tags: magento2, fonts, font-family, font-awesome

How is it possible to add to Magento 2 fonts `font-display: swap` ?

I don't find the correct way in the typography.less, or in a custom CSS file, it breaks all the CSS.

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/opensans/semibold/opensans-600',
    @font-weight: 600,
    @font-style: normal
);
```

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 2):

you can add it to your file _typography.less changed mixin 
`.lib-font-face(
  @family-name,
  @font-path,
  @font-weight: normal,
  @font-style: normal,
  @font-display: swap
) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: @family-name;
    src: url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: @font-weight;
    font-style: @font-style;
    font-display: swap;
  }
}`